# I am working in an outdated technology, should I move from this to some other new technology?

Tags: work-experience, career-switch, technology, company

I am working in MNC company for the past 1.5 years. As this is my my first job, I was asked to work in a support role. And the technology which they are using is outdated which does not have any scope in the market. For now I am the sole resource in the project and sometimes I'm required to work on weekends too.

I am already frustrated with this work and want to change my stream to some new technology. Right now I am confused, should I resign from the present job and update my skills for new technology or to get some experience in this job and switch the company.

Will it be hard to change company with changing the domain?

Should I resign from the current company as I am not getting time to update my skills and I am not happy with the work what I am doing?

Or

If I get experience in current project with this outdated technology, will it help me in the future?

Can anyone help me with this confusion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you discussed your preferences with your manager? If so, what did they say?

Comment: What is this outdated technology?

Comment: "should I resign" is not a question you're going to find an answer to here. At best, it's an opinion-based question, which is off-topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm a Junior Level Developer in a job that is not teaching me anything modern](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/40145/im-a-junior-level-developer-in-a-job-that-is-not-teaching-me-anything-modern)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing that wrong in working with old technologies.  I spent a lot of time maintaining an internal website written in Classic ASP and we have a ton of VB6 apps.  Working in these legacy technologies still has demand in the marketplace, so don't think that your current work is dead-end.

Having said that, I get where you're coming from.

Have a word with your manager and ask for some time on something newer, at least to vary your working environment and learn something new.  It might be the case that there's some upcoming projects (maybe re-writing this project you're on now) that your manager has in mind.

In the meantime, speak to your manager and indicate that you enjoy doing what you're doing now, but would like some time to upskill in more modern technologies.

Answer (score 1):

Mention the old tech stack that you are working on in your post. That would help others to share their knowledge on the future job prospective w.r.t that technology.

Discuss with your manager about your willingness to work on new tech stack. If s/he agrees to it and shows a roadmap to you, then it is all good.

Else, what I would suggest is hold on to your current job and this is crucial during this pandemic. Do not overlook this. Try learning new skills from any online portals. Apply for any internship or part time job elsewhere. Be specific with your commitment time, say 2-4 hours a day. Do not overpromise anything for these kind of jobs.

This way, when the pandemic situation ends, you would be having enough industry experience, years wise and also an internship/part time job experience in the new technology. Both these would be helpful for you to apply for a new job.

Answer (score 0):

> If I get experience in current project with this outdated technology, will it help me in future?

It's a niche, older technologies are still relevant and you do learn skills that are usable elsewhere. But if you don't want to be cornered into a niche then 1.5 years is long enough to get everything useful in.

Whether you want to work on other technologies outside work or not is up to you, but I can't see you learning much more that is useful outside the niche by staying longer.

I've been around for a long time as an engineer so I know a lot of the stuff I worked on a decade ago is still relevant with newer tech. BUT, I can train the directly relevant bits in a week that I gained over years.